# Can I increase Windows 7 start menu vertical size to let more items fit in it?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I hate putting shortcuts/files on desktop as well as crawling through "All Programs" menu any frequently (and I only pin some essential every-day applications to the task bar). So, I put all the programs I occasionally use to the start menu itself (above the automatic recently used programs section). But even though I've switched it to use small icons, I run out of vertical space in it (just about 16 shortcuts fit there at maximum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this links, maybe it will be helpful for you

- http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/25776-start-menu-change-height.html
- http://windows7forums.com/tweaks-guides-howto/18866-tutorial-how-increase-decrease-height-start-menu.html

Comment: To whom it may concern, I tried the 1st link and the guide works!

Answer (score 3):

You could change these values:

[image: Start menu - properties]
[image: properties - tab start menu]